# Missing requirement: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http 3.6.0 requires 'java.package; java.net.http 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Tags: jetty, osgi, eclipse-rcp, cxf, java-11

We are upgrading **jetty** from version `9.4.30` to `10.0.15` and `cxf` from version `3.3.7` to `3.6.0`.

After upgrade, while building the repo, we are getting below error:

> Missing requirement: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http 3.6.0 requires 'java.package; java.net.http 0.0.0' but it could not be found

**Note:** We are using Java 11 and Eclipse 4.23.

JDK compliance level is set to `11`.
[Maven and java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0mAS.png)
JAVA_HOME path set to jave11

Comment: [The package `java.net.http` is contained in the system library since Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html). How do you build your repo? With Maven/Tycho? If yes, make sure to run Maven with Java 11 or higher (which is not the case according to the error message).

Comment: We are building repo using maven and using Java11

Comment: Which Tycho version? Please show a [minimal `pom.xml` with which your issue can be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the whole error message not only a small part of it.

Comment: We are using 2.1.0 tycho version.

Comment: This issue is resolved after Tycho updating to 2.5.0